# C# - Creating (Blazor) input elements based on generic list with generic objects

Tags: c#, blazor, bind

I want to generate a form based on a generic list with generic objects in blazor. And I'm running into some issues that I can't seem to find the solutions to. Maybe the way I'm trying it is simply impossible in blazor?

My current attempt involves using this model:

```
    public class Form
{
    public string FormName{ get; set; }
    public List<Field<object>> FieldList{ get; set; } = new List<Field<object>>();
    public bool Stuff{ get; set; }
    public int SomeMoreStuff{ get; set; }
}

public class Field<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public FieldInfo Info { get; set; }
}
```

And would like something like this in my editform (ultimately switch on datatype instead of the one if):

```
foreach(Field<object> field in model.FieldList)
{
  if (field.FieldInfo.DataTypeCode == "text")
  {
   <InputText @bind-Value="field.Value" /> 
  }
}
```

In this case model.FieldList is filled with data.

The code above doesn't work (inexplicable null reference at runtime when trying to render the form). So I was wondering if there was another way I should be trying or maybe this should work but I goofed somewhere in my code?)

The interesting part is that this *does* work if I use @onchange instead of bind-Value. However, I would also have to change the blazor elements to regular html tags, as I would otherwise be lacking a ValueExpression. And when adding that I end up with the same null reference.

**My question**: Is there a way to use generic objects out of a generic list to bind to different types of input fields, while using blazor elements (and bind-Value) instead of html tags (and @onchange)?

Comment: Since when did a `string` have a `Value` property? Or, going back a step; since when is a `Field<anything>` a `string`?

Comment: https://github.com/BrianLParker/ModelToComponent

Comment: First of all a Field<type> can't be of type string, because it's always the type of 'Field', but you can add a function which requires Type as parameter and check that against the Field's typeof(T). Aside of that you can make use of dynamic components. Add your type-checking-method and if condition is met load the configured component type ([useful link](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/a92dea29-3218-4d1c-a132-9671b518d1f4.aspx))

Comment: Yes there is, but you need a good working knowledge of generics and `T` conversion tricks.  You can review the MS DotNetCore code Repo on Github for input controls such as `InputNumber` (https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Components/Web/src/Forms/InputNumber.cs) for some pointers.  Your code suggests you're trying to build a generic form editor.  Many a good programmer has travelled that rocky road!

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers. I have some more research to do clearly.

That's my bad for typing the question too quick. I use a different check than "field is string" code to figure out the datatype of the Field, based on data in FieldInfo (basically just a switch on a string code that defines the type).  Editted.

Do you think the null reference is a cause of bad conversions or is it linked to blazor behaviour? It confused me why html tags with @onchange work while blazor elements with bind-Value gives the nullref at runtime in blazor code.

Thanks for the useful links